# How do I infinitely loop content in AfterEffects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I want to scroll these images from top to bottom. When they start to exit the bottom I want to them to re-enter from the top - therefore creating the illusion of infinite scrolling

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your construction of the elements but basically you'll want to create a keyframe with it right back in its starting position after the final frame of it leaving. You can do this either with individual boxes or with the "group" of boxes.

If you intend to have it re-enter before the last one leaves you'll have to either do it as individual boxes, or using a duplicate of the group.

Then save that part as a composition and either in AE or more likely in Premier you'll loop it as many times as you want it to run (or all the way to the end of your video)

Answer (score 3):

This video shows how to infinitely loop a composition using expresions: https://youtu.be/aZ3y7YBPuoU

This video https://youtu.be/_CcB33iLWvc shows two methods: 
      1) copy/paste 
     *2) use the "Motion Tile" effect in After Effects, and animate the 'Tile Center' width.

*Motion Tile seems to be the easiest method.

Comment: Welcome to gd.SE! We're looking for complete answers, not just one-liners with a link. Can you expand your answer to explain how exactly to use expressions in this case?